# Add a "*" to a label with jQuery if element does not contain a "*"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having trouble with this.  Try to check if a label element contains a "*" anywhere in it and if the parent div has data-required="1" - if it does do nothing.  If it does not add "* ".

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/9ekvrm8x/6/

```
$("div[data-required='1'] label").prepend( "* " );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$("div[data-required='1'] label:not(:contains('*'))").prepend( "* " );
```

It matches only labels that *don't* already have an asterisk.

### Fiddle

Answer (score 0):

If i understand right you can use jquery [contains](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.contains/):

```
$("div[data-required='1'] label:contains('*')").prepend( "* " );
```

Also you can use `:not` with `:empty`:

```js
$("div[data-required='1'] label:not(:contains('*')):not(:empty)").prepend( "* " );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>test Me</p>
<div data-required="1">
    <label>E-mail Address</label>
</div>
<div data-required="1">
    <label class="test">E-mail Address</label>
</div>
<div data-required="1">
    <label></label>
</div>
<div>
    <label>E-mail Address *</label>
</div>
<div>
    <label>*E-mail Address</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry had wrong Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/9ekvrm8x/6/

Need to only a * if one is not in the content.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div[data-required='1'] label").not(":contains('*')").prepend( "* " );
```

Comment: Please explain how this fixes the problem described in the question.

Comment: The code simply chains a filter condition (not contains) on the required label set.

Comment: You should explain this in the answer, not in a comment.

Comment: Dear Al, this code doesn't deserve a lot of explanation. Do you know fluent programming?

Comment: You should take a look at the Help center > [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): *Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better*.